# Update with inner join = Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, mysql-error-1111

I am getting the 1111 error in the post title when executing the query below. Basically, I am try to update table 1 (special_valuation_temp) with data from table 2 (search_upload_quotes). I want to get the minimum and maximum quote values to update table 1 with.

```
UPDATE special_valuation_temp svt 
       INNER JOIN search_upload_quotes suq 
               ON ( svt.clei = suq.clei 
                     OR svt.partnumber = suq.partnumber ) 
SET    svt.vendor_low = ( Min(suq.priceperunit) * svt.qty ), 
       svt.vendor_high = ( Max(suq.priceperunit) * svt.qty ) 
WHERE  suq.submitted = 1 
       AND suq.priceperunit > 0;
```

It seems that I can't use the MIN() and MAX() functions in the SET clause. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you think of using a sub select for this?

Comment: Yes. It's much too slow for over a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's incorrect without the use of `group by`. You can rather get the `min()` and `max()` value first in a subquery and perform a `join` with that subquery result and do your calculation as-is.